# play framework "tag" motivation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I looked in the [documentation here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaTemplateUseCases) to make sure I really squeeze the most of play's templating.

I am hard to find any inspiration in the code example under `Tags` there.

Can you suggest a different minimal example, that makes sense in the world of front-end programming? Here's an adapted version of the code there that is a bit less weird than the original, but still seems to do little to inspire a good style of usage or motivation:

notice.scala.html:

```
@(level: String = "error")(body: (String) => Html)

@level match {

  case "success" => {
    <p class="success">
      @body("green")
    </p>
  }

  case "warning" => {
    <p class="warning">
      @body("orange")
    </p>
  }

  case "error" => {
    <p class="error">
      @body("red")
    </p>
  }

}
```

noticeTest.scala.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    @notice("success") { autoColor => <span style="color:@autoColor">something happened now</span> }
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you conceive a useful example of a "tag"? I feel that code is trying to inspire me with something I do not fathom.

In particular I didn't really grasp why supplying a function to `notice` would belong in the chosen scenario of showing an error message in a neat way, or in an html templating scenario in general. I am curious about it...

Best I could say is, it's a way to wrap html with a derived value, essentially plugging in an automatically calculated value into the html. But this is too much boilerplate in `noticeTest.scala.html` for accomplishing such goal.

Comment: An example: a tag `@formatDate(date)` that returns a Date object in a specific format (ex: "DD-MM-YYYY", "3 hours ago")

Comment: Regarding the example in Play documentation, I think it was meant to show that you can pass blocks between the tag and the caller (in my exp. templating systems usually only accept simple expressions like variable names and filters). It indeed adds too much boilerplate, but lets you specify exactly what HTML gets rendered...